# NetLogo help using function "let"

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

We are modeling an interaction between two agents using the function "let" similar to the wolf-sheep model. When the agent1 is in the same space as agent2, agent2 (prey) needs to get the variable a with the same value as the variable a from agent1 (predator).

Something similar to:

```
ask agents [
  let prey one-of agents-here [
    ask prey set a "the variable a from agent"
    ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I think you want (not tested) is this:

```
ask agents
[ let prey one-of agents-here
  ask prey
  [ set varname [varname] of myself
  ]
]
```

It appears your question is not really about `let`, which is simply saying 'make the variable value the result of some statement'. Since the not-coded bit was about how to obtain the value of 'variable a of agent' then I think your question was about `myself`.

The bit `[] of` says 'get the value of a variable belonging to some agent' and `myself` sort of jumps out a level of brackets to find the agent to which the variable belongs.

As a side note, it's probably not a good idea to have 'agents' as your `turtles` `breed` because it will be difficult to talk about your model - the word 'agent' will refer to one of your types of agent as well as being the general class of agents.